# How to make localhost rest api work with react-native?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, react-native

I have been trying to fetch some values from my spring boot localhost restapi. It is throwing a network error. I have tried to fetch with `Axios.get()` too but no result.I have given CORS(origins='*') in my springboot class and method too.

```
async componentDidMount()
{

  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/jobSeeker/allJobSeekers');  

   const body = await response.json();   

   this.setState({ users: body, isLoading: false });

   console.log(users);
}
```

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\core\whatwg-fetch.js:504:29 in onerror
>   - node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172:43 in dispatchEvent
>   - ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

Answer (score 1):

The `localhost` of your emulator or device is not the same as the `localhost` of your computer. You can map ports between the two, in this case `adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080` will map `localhost:8080` on your emulator/device to `localhost:8080` on your computer.

Comment: Thank you so much, brother !! Working like a charm. This is my first question in StackOverflow. You've saved my time. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: @Lokeshch if this answered your question, please select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For people like me who are searching for a solution (add android-dev in scripts), replace the port with your localhost port and rerun the application.

`package.json` file:

```
{
   "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
   "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
   "scripts": {
   "start": "expo start",
   "android": "expo start --android",
   "ios": "expo start --ios",
   "web": "expo start --web",
   "eject": "expo eject",
   "android-dev": "adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080 && react-native run- android"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was :

1.)  Check your IPv4 address. Google on how you can get the IP address for your system.

Let the IP be: **192.168.xx.xx**

2.) Replace -

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/jobSeeker/allJobSeekers');
```

With -

```
const response = await fetch('http://192.168.xx.xx:8080/jobSeeker/allJobSeekers');
```

Notice the replacement of localhost with your IP address.

And that's it.