# Network request failed - fetching from localhost ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, react-native, localhost

I am getting a Network request failed when trying to fetch from localhost in ReactNative for both android and ios devices.

I've tried following previous solutions but nothing seemed to work for me. I followed this tutorial: https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/connecting-react-native-to-localhost-65e7ddf43d02

For iOS:
I edited the info.plist and added the following code and reinstalled the app on my simulator but it still didn't work.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

For Android:
I used my IP instead of 'localhost' for my fetching URL but it still didn't work. I also made configurations to AndroidManifest.xml following the steps in the tutorial but it still doesn't work.

Any other solutions???

PS. I am using a Macbook. My REST API is using SQL database and asp.net core. I am trying to fetch a json.

Error: Network Request Failed

Fetch code:

```
async getProjects1() {
    const response = await fetch('https://127.0.0.1:5001/api/projects');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ projects: data, loading: false }, function(){console.log(this.state.projects)});
  };
```

Comment: Can you post the error, please?

Comment: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):TypeError: Network request failed
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:25885:33
_callTimer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30389:17
callTimers@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30597:19
__callFunction@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2659:36
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2391:31
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2613:15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The error was not because of react native but from my asp.net core API. Basically, I just needed to change my code in the launchsettings.js in the Properties folder from `"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"` to `"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"`

This solved the issue and fetching from localhost in react native worked without any further issues. This stack question helped me figure this out: [How to fix network error in react-native when access localhost api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099563/how-to-fix-network-error-in-react-native-when-access-localhost-api)

Answer (score 1):

These solutions did not work.

What did work:

Download ngrok (https://ngrok.com/), signup, and connect your account. ngrok creates a private https localhost tunnel.

Setup - https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/setup

Unzip to install ngrok:

```
unzip /path/to/ngrok.zip
```

Connect your ngrok account (Non functioning example auth token):

```
ngrok config add-authtoken 2ySPR5UeS3Fjf5YAblNRe7ZcV1o_9sdf2SDFGHjEQaOCE6xEi
```

Use the command (with your port number):

```
ngrok http 8080
```

Once ngrok is online, replace your localhost API address:

```
http://localhost:8080 
http://127.0.0.1:8080
http://192.168.0.100:8080
```

With the forwarding web address (Non functioning example address):

```
https://ebda-61-137-45-130.ngrok.io
```

I've used ngrok for testing APIs on a variety of networks without issue. So far its the only foolproof method I've found for testing APIs using localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says that there is unhandled promise rejection, so i'd advise adding error handling as:

```
async getProjects1() {
    try {
    const response = await fetch('https://127.0.0.1:5001/api/projects');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ projects: data, loading: false }, function(){console.log(this.state.projects)});
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
}
```

and this issue may be resolved, or you at least might get clearer error message.

Comment: I am still getting an error saying  [TypeError: Network request failed]